# PropertyChangeSupport with weak references to PropertyChangeListener?

Tags: java, weak-references, propertychangesupport, propertychangelistener

Java does not seem to deliver an implementation of [PropertyChangeSupport](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) with weak references to registered [PropertyChangeListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html).

It would not be very hard to implement this, but before I re-invent the wheel, does anyone know whether such feature has been implemented in any open source library? It does not seem so, but someone may know better on SO.

Comment: Hi, what's your use case? Why do the listener references need to be weak? This *could* indicate that your listeners aren't unregistering themselves correctly.

Comment: @Paul I may need to expose such classes and won't have control on code which should unregister these listeners properly. It is a defensive approach.

Answer (score 2):

Would [this Netbeans WeakListeners page](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/WeakListeners.html) help ?

Example:

```
public class Observer {
  private Listener listener;

  private void registerTo(Source source) {
      listener = new Listener();
      source.addChangeListener(WeakListeners.change (listener, source));
  }

  private class Listener implements ChangeListener {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
          doSomething();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Somehow yes, though this implementation does not seem very clean (Javadoc says 'The unregistration is done using reflection').

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be as a result of its genericity I guess. It can act as a weak listener for several (any?) listener type that follows the Javabeans conventions.